# ngTable reload table with server side pagination

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ngtable

I've been playing smoothly with ngTable from a few weeks and now I'm facing a strange problem of doing 2 things simultaneously:

1. Fetching data from API with server side pagination.
2. Reloading table on user input.

While these two thing are quite easy to achieve when done separately, but are a bit tough when I'm trying to achieve them simultaneously.

**Screen:** A *Select* Menu, a *text* box, a *GO!* button and an ngTable.

**Case 1:** API gets called on the click of GO! button. `ng-click="loadTable()"` and the data is displayed in `#userTable`

```
$scope.loadTable = function () {
            $scope.filterParam = $scope.admin.selectedFilter;
            $scope.textParam = $scope.admin.enteredFilterText;
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10          // count per page
            }, {
                counts: [],
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                   $http.get($scope.admin.baseUrl + "/Api/User/GetUsersProjects?strKey=" + $scope.filterParam + "&strValue=" + $scope.textParam).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.admin.tableData = response.data.Users;
                    $scope.admin.totalRecords = response.data.TotalRecords;
                });
                        var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.admin.tableData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.admin.tableData;
                        params.total($scope.admin.totalRecords);
                        $defer.resolve(orderedData);
                }
            });
            $("#userTable").show();
        }
```

***Problem with Case-1***: Pagination did not work.

**Case 2:** API gets called in the `init()` method's `getData:` method and a pageIndex is passed with the API call.

```
init();
function init() {
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10          // count per page
    }, {
        counts: [],
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
           $http.get($scope.admin.baseUrl + "/Api/User/GetUsersProjects?strKey=" + $scope.filterParam + "&strValue=" + $scope.textParam + "&pageIndex=" + params.page()).then(function (response) {
            $scope.admin.tableData = response.data.Users;
            $scope.admin.totalRecords = response.data.TotalRecords;
        });
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.admin.tableData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.admin.tableData;
                params.total($scope.admin.totalRecords);
                $defer.resolve(orderedData);

        }
    });
};

$scope.loadTable = function () {
    $scope.filterParam = $scope.admin.selectedFilter;
    $scope.textParam = $scope.admin.enteredFilterText;
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
    $("#userTable").show();
}
```

***Problem with Case-2***: I'm not able to refresh the table on the changed user input(If user changes his input and clicks `GO!` after the table is rendered one time). Because, `ngTable` refuses to re-create the instance of tableParams(I'm not sure what happens here)

**JSON Structure of output by API:**

```
{
    "PageSize": 10,
    "TotalRecords": 1,
    "Users": [
        {
            "ID": 12,
            "FirstName": "Vibhor",
            "LastName": "Dube",
            "UserID": "vibhord",
            "Email": "vibhord@vibhor.com",
            "Phone": "111",
            "Fax": "1233243",
            "IsActive": true,
            "Projects": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

It is working by doing this:

```
$scope.applyFilters = function (x, y, z) {
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
};

$scope.getTableData = function($defer, params) {
    $http.get(getUrl)
    .success(function (response, status) {
     if  (status==200) {
     var data = response._embedded.players;
     var orderedData = params.$params.sorting ?
     $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :data;
     params.total(response.total_items);
     $defer.resolve(orderedData);

    }

    })
};

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: $scope.page_count // show first page
    , count: $scope.page_length    // count per page
   }, {
   total: 0, // length of data
   counts: [10 ,20 ,50 ,100],
   getData: $scope.getTableData
 });
```

getUrl will vary according to the filter we are calling in apply filter function